# Gparted doesn't see HDD

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

I wan't to resize my Linux partition. To do that I boot in a Ubuntu 14.04 live USB drive and open gparted.
Now the thing is that Gparted only shows my usb drive and not my HDD. Can't choose my HDD under devices.

Same thing also when i open Gparted after normal boot:
Gparted doesn't show my HDD when the usb drive is pluged in.
As soon as the USB drive is not plugged in it shows my HDD normaly with al the partitions.

Here the output of fdisk -l after normal bootup:

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/nvme0n1'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 256.1 GB, 256060514304 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31130 cylinders, total 500118192 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x9a04939e

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/nvme0n1p1               1   500118191   250059095+  ee  GPT

Disk /dev/sda: 8002 MB, 8002732032 bytes
241 heads, 36 sectors/track, 1801 cylinders, total 15630336 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          32    15630335     7815152    b  W95 FAT32
```

Comment: With NVMe device you need newer gparted. gparted should be at least version 0.24.0-1 to recognize NVMe devices
http://gparted.sourceforge.net/index.php Or use 16.04 Ubuntu which has a newer gparted v25. You probably need 16.04 anyway for full support of NVMe.